# Matter beyond the event horizon should time travel?

Tags: black-holes, faster-than-light, event-horizon, time-travel

when anything passes the event horizon of a blackhole, it must be moving faster than light as even light cannot escape. So then, shoundnt it time travel?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be mistaking something here. The event horizon is the point which light can't escape because of the black holes extreme gravitational influence not because the black hole is pulling it in faster than *c* nothing can go faster than *c*.

If you mean time dilation this question doesn't make sense still because anything going *c* or greater than *c* can't experience time there is no reference. Hope this helps.